# Getting: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: error on Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-routing

I’m newbie with AngularJS, and I ran into problems with AngularJS tutorial 7 at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 when running it on Chrome. On Chrome I get the following error on console:

```
angular.js:10126 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective
    at VALIDITY_STATE_PROPERTY (angular.js:78)
    at angular.js:3801
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:3929)
    at angular.js:3806
    at getService (angular.js:3929)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:3956)
    at angular.js:3807
    at getService (angular.js:3929)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:3956)
    at angular.js:5716
```

Screenshot

[image]

At the same time the Web page/AngularJS works on Internet Explorer and Opera, so I guess this could be some kind of Chrome specific issue perhaps? Below is IE view of the same page, and it works okay.

[image]

The code I'm using is identical to the one available for the tutorial, but I have listed the app.js and the controllers.js files just in case below.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);


phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */


var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
  }]);
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-phonecat",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.x",
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.x",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-route": "1.3.x"
  }
}
```

Currently, I'm going through tutorial nro 7, which covers routing. Tutorials 1-6 didn't use routing, and the page worked fine on Chrome. So the issue might have somethin to do with routing.

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of angular.js you are using?

Comment: Angular version you are using ..??

Comment: @pankajparkar  I checked its  AngularJS v1.3.10 and that's what I found in the angular files that reside in bower_component subfolders

Comment: @squiroid  I checked its  AngularJS v1.3.10 and that's what I found in the angular files that reside in bower_component subfolders

Comment: angular.route version is old or new? try upgrade you angular to 1.3.3. and angular-route 1.3

Comment: @pankajparkar at the top of the angular-route.js file it says AngularJS v1.3.10, I'm going to update my question and add bower.json file content just in case

Comment: @pankajparkar I upgraded first changing bower.json file by specifying angular version 1.3.3 and then angular-route 1.3 and it didn't work. I mean I got an error when running: npm install command -->npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install` .. npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,.. Btw,did I update those angular versions correctly with Bower? Anyway,I think as long as the routing works either on IE or Opera I'll manage.However, test worked on Chrome. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jyrkim You're welcome...That was the problem with angular versions may be.:)

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the issue why it wasn’t working on **Chrome** wasn’t only related to the browser alone; it was also an issue with **Node.js**. The tutorial instructs to use Node.js as the Web server for the tutorial, which worked fine until tutorial nro 7, that had routing used for partial views. Now it looks like for some reason, the routing doesn’t work on Chrome when Node.js is used as the Web server. I discovered this when I tried to use Apache instead of Node.js for Web server. After hosting the tutorial Web project on **Apache**, the routing started to function correctly on **Chrome**. So it looks like the issue had something to do with Chrome and Node.js.

My **Node.js** version is **v0.10.33** (so it wasn't the latest version available).

Below is a screenshot of **Chrome** when Web page is hosted on **Apache**.

[image]